# How to create a script to export each product with all images, names, SKUs, dimensions as a CSV programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, csv, script

```
**This is a working code**
**You Create a file path as i.e.
http://localhost/magento241/exportproduct.php**

<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');
$fileFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');
$csvProcessor = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\File\Csv');
$directoryList = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

$content[] = [
    'sku' => __('sku'),
    'name' => __('name'),
    'value' => __('images'),
    'image-width' => __('dimensions'),
];

$fileName = 'product_export.csv';
$filePath = $directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . "/" . $fileName;

foreach ($collection as $product){
    $productFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById($product->getId());
    $productImages = $productFactory->getMediaGalleryEntries();
    $label = '';
    $productImageData = [];
    foreach ($productImages as $image) {
        $productImageData[] = "pub/media/catalog/product".$image->getFile();
    }

    foreach ($productImageData as $imageData) {
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imageData);
        $imagesDetails = explode('/',$imageData);
        $content[] = [
            $product->getSku(),
            $product->getName(),
            $imagesDetails[count($imagesDetails) - 1],
            $width.'x'.$height
        ];
    }
}

$csvProcessor->setEnclosure('"')->setDelimiter(',')->saveData($filePath, $content);
$fileFactory->create($fileName, ['type' => "filename",
    'value' => $fileName,
    'rm' => true,
], DirectoryList::MEDIA, 'text/csv', null);
```

[image: Result in CSV format]

Comment: if its working then whats an issue..?

Comment: I'm new to Stack, so I'm going to help someone with this. That's why I'm adding my question and answer. There is no problem with this script.

Comment: I don't know, how to add my own question and answer in this StackExchange so.